# Using react hooks, why fetched data is undefined?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I am still new and learning React.

I followed a tutorial but I am keep getting error message saying

'Cannot read property 'name' of undefined' .

I have hosted my code here : https://codesandbox.io/embed/sleepy-hellman-uf1h3

I am not sure why this is undefined as the object is available.  I can access the object when I do console.log(mandatoryArticle)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The first time the component renders `mandatoryArticle[0]` will not be set.  So, you just need to be a bit defensive:

```
<h2 id="modal-title">mandatoryArticle[0] && mandatoryArticle[0].name}</h2>
```

Comment: Thanks for the comment.  I did suspected the sequence but does this mean that I have to do that for all places?

Comment: Yes, you need to account for all places where data is fetched asynchronously. You could do this by setting initial values, or by putting in defensive code.

Answer (score 1):

You are settings mandatoryArticle as empty array and then you are acessing 0 index in that empty array. You propably missunderstood useEffect hook. It is not synchronous. The sequence is set mandatoryArticle => render => fetch => set articles => render.